# How stable is mysql 5.5.13

Tags: mysql, webserver, installation

Appears like it is stable enough to use professionally: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,421981

---

I was assigned to set up a web server with mysql for a company and they said they NEED a stable version. Is mysql 5.5.13 stable? I was about to download it from the site when I saw that it was still beta...

How can 5.5.8 be stable but 5.5.13 still be in beta? Is there anyway I can download mysql 5.5.8? Apparently it is stable: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,421981

Comment: Example, mysql.com release a statement saying 5.5.8 is "stable" - I wouldn't mind downloading 5.5.8 it's just I can't seem to find it. I was wondering if 5.5.13 has that same "stable" status and should/could be used for professional production. I have since found the answer here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,421981. You can close it.

Comment: Eh, I only got involved because of flags, and agreed with the subj/arg because of what I mentioned.  You know, I learned something today... Sometimes software teams use different jargon, and sometimes that jargon gives a false impression to other developers out there.  I think we all need to learn to trust our fellow developers more.  I don't think I'll be closing this today.  *eye tears up*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the stie, the current generally available release is 5.5.13. When it is labeled as a release, it is considered a release build (what you and your client are most likely calling "stable"). It is certainly stable enough to have been released as a release build.

The interim builds are labeled as such, and should be treated like betas. I am not sure where you drill down to these builds these days.

Short answer: You should be fine downloading and using the version in question.

Comment: Okay, I just noticed that the only thing that says "beta" is the installer. I guess the installer isn't completely ready? Thanks!

Comment: I have not noticed that, but most of my playing with databases other than SQL Server these days is on my own time. ;-)